# GCP compliance manager - are there API to download reports?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pci-compliance

I need to pro-grammatically  download few compliance reports available at GCP compliance manager link - https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/compliance-reports-manager

are there API available to do so

thanks

Comment: Hi,
I was also trying to find the APIs to download the report from compliance manager.

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to find the APIs to download the report from compliance manager. I did not find any relevant one, but I found a policy analyzer which can be used to identify the compliance issues. Sharing below if that can help someone looking for the same.

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/policyanalyzer/rest/